# Update sum with trigger

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to sum basket item price values and insert it into a payment as total price. I am trying to use a trigger for this but I am getting error near `SET total_price =`. Error msg: Expected expression, got 'select'. How do I deal with this?

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION make_sum() RETURNS TRIGGER
AS $$
    BEGIN
        UPDATE payment
            SET total_price = select sum(price) from basket where basket_id = new.basket_id;
        RETURN NULL;
END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
CREATE TRIGGER make_sum AFTER INSERT ON basket FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE make_sum()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the updated version. I have made the following changes to your script:

1. Put the select in your update statement within parentheses
2. Added the keyword 'PROCEDURE' in your trigger definition.

```html
CREATE FUNCTION make_sum() RETURNS TRIGGER
    AS $$
        BEGIN
            UPDATE payment
                SET total_price = (select sum(price) from basket where basket_id = new.basket_id);
            RETURN NULL;
    END;$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    
CREATE TRIGGER make_sum
AFTER INSERT ON basket FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE make_sum();
```

Comment: what does the procedure do?

Comment: do you know what might be the reason for this not working with `uuid` as basket id? The value is null all the time in payment and not updating it :/